# How do I delete the first node in a doubly-linked list?

Tags: c++

My list is structured like this:

```
struct Node {
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    T datum;
};
Node *first;   // points to first Node in list, or 0 if list is empty
Node *last;    // points to last Node in list, or 0 if list is empty
```

I've attempted to do the following:

```
void pop_front()
{
     //copied from lecture slides
     assert(!empty());
     Node *victim = first;
     first = first->next;
     if(first != 0)
     {
         first->prev = 0;
     }
     delete victim;
     victim=0;
}
```

The problem is, it is giving me a memory leak when I do the delete victim line. I don't know what's wrong.

edit: this is how I am adding a node:

```
 //MODIFIES: this
    //EFFECTS:  inserts i into the front of the list
    void pushit_tofront(const T &datum)
    {
        //if list is empty, update both the first and last element
        //copied from lecture slides
        Node *p = new Node;
        p->datum = datum;
        p->next = first;
        if(empty())
        {
            first = last = p;
        }
        else
        {
            first = p;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you know it's giving you a memory leak?

Comment: this is what it's saying: "error for object 0x100102c80: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
"

Comment: Off topic: Recommend replacing those `0`s with `nullptr` and `victim=0;` is not much use. It's about to go out of scope.

Comment: How do you add nodes?

Comment: Ensure `Node`s are created with `new` and ensure `first` and `last` are initialized (currently need to be set to 0, but see comment above).

Comment: Proabably, you didn't allocate the memory to `Node *first` i.e..use `Node * first = new Node;`  instead.

Comment: You've eliminated not using `new`. That leaves an uninitialized `first` as the prime suspect.

Comment: You don't initialize p->prev or first->prev.

Comment: since you are using c++, why don't you create a constructor for Node where the member variables are initialized?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code for node

```
 class Node {
   public:
        int get() { return object; }; // returns the value of the element
        void set(int object) { this->object = object; }; // set the value of the element

        Node* getNext() { return nextNode; }; // get the address of the next node
        void setNext(Node* nextNode) // set the address of the next node
         { this->nextNode = nextNode; };

        Node* getPrev() { return prevNode; }; // get the address of the prev node
        void setPrev(Node* prevNode) // set the address of the prev node
         { this->prevNode = prevNode; };

 private:
        int object; // it stores the actual value of the element
        Node* nextNode; // this points to the next node
        Node* prevNode; // this points to the previous node
     };
```

Doubly link list look like this it is uncompleted. but you have to only add the remove function in it.

```
class DoublyList
{
public:
        List();
        void add (int addObject);
        int get();
        bool next();
        void start();
        void remove();


private:
        int size;
        Node * headNode;
        Node * currentNode;
        Node * lastCurrentNode;
};
```

Doubly link list remove it will remove from any location. you have asked about first node the last two if condition will help you.

```
DoublyList::remove(){
    Node *removeNode= currentNode;

    if((currentNode->getNext()!=null)&&(currentNode->getprev())!=headNode)){ // it will remove the node in middle
    lastCurrentNode->setNext(currentNode->getNext());
    (currentNode->getNext())->setPrev(currentNode->getPrev);
    currentNode= currentNode->getNext();
    }

    if((currentNode->getprev())!=headNode)&&(currentNode->getNext()==null)){   // it will remove the node if it is last node
    lastCurrentNode->setNext(null);
    currentNode= lastCurrentNode;
    lastCurretnNode= currentNode->getPrev();
    }

    if((currentNode->getprev())==headNode)&&(currentNode->getNext()==null)){ //if it is at the start and next node is null
        headNode->setNext(null);
    lastCurrentNode= headNode;
    currentNode= headNode;
    }

        if((currentNode->getprev())==headNode)&&(currentNode->getNext()!=null)){  //if it is at the start and next node is not null
        headNode->setNext(currentNode->getNext());
        (currentNode->getNext())->setPrev(headNode);
    lastCurrentNode= headNode;
    currentNode= currentNode->getNext();
    }



    delete removeNode;
    size--;
}
```

I think you are trying to make stack using doubly link list. but it is  not clear in you question. so i have written the remove method in all condition. i have not tested this code.you have to do it by self.if there is any mistake you can contact with me.

Answer (score -2):

Concerning the issue of academic honesty, I am not going to post the solution, as this is a popular assignment.

However, I will give you some pointers :)

Anytime you are doing a mutation of a doubly-linked list you have (in your case) at most six pointers to worry about.

```
curr->next = ?
curr->prev = ?
next->prev = ?
next->next = ?
head = ?
tail = ?
```

If you are definitively assuring that all those pointers are being managed properly, you will probably resolve your current issue.

Comment: Not the downvoter since you are mostly right. I suggest an edit to improve the mostly: It's most likely an uninitialized pointer, not a null pointer. You can `delete` a null pointer just fine. `delete` checks and does nothing for a null pointer. It could also be some bug in unshown code that tramples  `first`. No way to know for sure.

Comment: That's what I figured, that's why I suggested all the pointers to manage. My guess is the poster down-voted because I didn't give them the code.